# Is exchanging integral and sum this way allowed?

Tags: integration, summation

Suppose I have

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!}\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin(2(k-y)x)e^{-x}dx.$$

Can I move the entire integral outside as its own transform by linearity since it is only integrating with respect to $x,$ as

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!}\sin(2(k-y)x) \right)e^{-x}dx?$$

Answer (score 1):

The question is whether the following change of the order of integration and summation is valid:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\int_0^\infty f_k(x)\,dx = \int_0^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty f_k(x)\,dx,
$$
where
$$
f_k(x) = \frac{1}{k!}\sin(2(k-y)x)\,e^{-x}.
$$
Here $y$ is treated as a fixed real number. If the series in question were merely a finite sum, then we could freely exchange the sum and the integral. However, when infinitely many summands are involved, justifying this operation becomes more involved, and there are relatively simple examples where the order of summation and integration matters, i.e., the two sides of the equation we want to establish are not equal.

If we want to use the Riemann integral, then there are theorems about whether or not such operations are allowed, and in that case the question often hinges on whether the series $\sum_k f_k(x)$ [converges uniformly](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Uniform_convergence) in $x$. Since the integral involved is over the domain $[0,\infty)$, and not a compact interval, there lies an additional complication where justifying the interchange of summation and integration will likely involve truncating the interval to compact subintervals of the form $[0,M]$ for $0 < M < \infty$, and then inspecting what happens as $M\to\infty$.

That all said, the simplest approach is probably to interpret all of the integrals in sight as [Lebesgue integrals](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Lebesgue_integration). Doing so, the [Fubini-Tonelli theorem](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Fubini%27s_theorem#/Fubini%E2%80%93Tonelli_theorem) asserts that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\int_0^\infty |f_k(x)|\,dx = \int_0^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty |f_k(x)|\,dx,
$$
where if one side is $\infty$, then so is the other, and if one side is finite, then the other side is equal to it. Moreover, if either of the expressions in the last line is finite, then the operation we want to perform is valid, i.e.,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\int_0^\infty f_k(x)\,dx = \int_0^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty f_k(x)\,dx.
$$
So, all we have to do is show that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\int_0^\infty |f_k(x)|\,dx < \infty$. To do so, we estimate the $\sin(2(k-y)x)$ term by $1$ and we have:
\begin{align*}
|f_k(x)| \le \frac{1}{k!}e^{-x},
\end{align*}
so by [the monotonicity property of integration](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-monotonicity-property-of-the-lebesgue-integral-of-lebesg), we have
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\int_0^\infty |f_k(x)|\,dx \le \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k!}\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\,dx = \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k!} < \infty,
$$
where any of a number of means for establishing the convergence of a series can be used to show the last series in the line above is finite. (For example, one could use [direct comparison](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Direct_comparison_test) with the geometric series $\sum_k 2^{-k}$.) By the Fubini-Tonelli theorem, the operation we want to perform on our original series/integral is valid.

Comment: It looks like you're relying on positive-definiteness, but the function oscillates, so how does this resolve the issue?

Comment: @JRRs: Indeed the function oscillates, but the terms $1/k!$ and $e^{-x}$ "overwhelm" the oscillation. What I showed is that $f_k(x)$ satisfies the hypotheses of the Fubini-Tonelli theorem, which is why the interchange is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and the reason is simple - the addition rule.  If you have:

$$\int (du + dq) $$

We can break this integral up at the plus sign, givin:

$$\int du + \int dq $$

Because these are equivalent, we can also reverse the process.

A summation is just a whole lot of these squeezed together.  So, therefore, you can bump the summation on either side of the integral because of this rule.

Now let's look at the factor out in front.  Let's look at a simpler problem:

$$\sum_{k = 1}^3 k \int dx$$

This would expand to:

$$1\int dx + 2 \int dx + 3 \int dx$$

Now, constants can also jump across the integral, so this can become:

$$\int 1 dx + \int 2dx + \int 3dx $$

And, with the addition rule, this becomes:

$$\int(1dx + 2dx + 3dx)$$

This can be rewritten as:

$$\int \sum_{k = 1}^3 k \,dx$$

So, we can see that the summation rule and the constant multiplier rule allow for this kind of integral-jumping.

Comment: This only works if the function inside the integral is convergent. It happens to be convergent, but you haven't explained why.

Comment: Please consider that I am almost totally ignorant in this area.  I was surprised by your answer.  I thought that that (in general) $\int \left(\sum f(x)\right) dx = \sum \left( \int fx dx\right) \iff f(x)$ had uniform continuity.  Further my **blind instinct** is that uniform continuity on $f(x)$ is directly linked to whether $|f'(x)|$ is bounded.  On this basis, I would have **blindly** surmised that the step has to be valid because $|f'(x)|$ has to be bounded.  The only potential danger is the $k$ coefficient inside the sine function.  But this is offset by the $(1/k!)$ factor.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that. The convergence isn't an issue outside of theory to determine which function spaces you can generalize to, you'd obviously get non-nonsensical results if the exchanged sum was divergent anyway for practical purposes.

Comment: @TobyMak - I don't think convergence/divergence actually matters as much as you think it does.  If you limit yourself to the reals, yes, but if you extend it to the hyperreals then I'm pretty sure divergence winds up mattering very little.  For instance see https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.11342 If I get time I'll double-check on this.

Comment: I think you are oversimplifying things. Indeed in the case of finitely many summands, there is no issue, but in the case of a proper series (infinitely many nonzero summands), there can be a legitimate obstruction to the equality $\int \sum f_n = \sum \int f_n$. One case where we have equality is when $f_n \ge 0$ for all $n$, and then either both sides are infinite, or both sides are finite and equal. Another is when $\int \sum |f_n| < \infty$ (i.e., we have absolute convergence). This theorem is known as the Fubini-Tonelli theorem.

Comment: @AlexOrtiz Using hyperreals greatly simplifies things.  It basically allows you to apply all of the things you know about the finite to the infinite.

Comment: I don't actually know anything about the hyperreals, and I suspect many others would be in the same boat as me, where they know some analysis along the lines of something like Rudin's books. There, propositions such as the one in the question are proved via what I'd consider the "standard toolkit," i.e., essentially using little more than completeness of $\mathbb R$, some topology, and plenty of inequalities along the way. I think it would be interesting to know how one proves (even formulates) this proposition in terms of hyperreals, but to set that up, I imagine, is not trivial.

Comment: That said, I am wary of merely pointing to the hyperreal number system as a kind of "panacea" for the analytic technicalities of what I just called the "standard toolkit" in my last comment, since like I said I don't have any background with it, but still it's not hard for me to imagine that settings things up properly using the hyperreal number system poses its own challenges. I think that often what we pay for a "convenient" or "easy" way of describing things is a large amount of work somewhere else, say, in the foundations!

Comment: I've actually found that, with students, students find hyperreals a lot easier.  Basically, what we have developed without the benefit of hyperreals are a system of hacks and kludges built around not having well-structured infinities.  The hyperreals fix that, and all of the hacks and kludges disappear.  The nice rule from the hyperreals is the "transfer principle", which says, basically, that all first-order propositions valid in the Reals is also valid in the hyperreals. Therefore, as long as you assign $\infty$ to a hyperreal value, it works.

Comment: To be more specific, since we have established that the swapping of $\sum\int$ with $\int\sum$ works fine for the non-infinite reals, the same proposition continues to hold in the hyperreals, even when using an infinite value.